# OffscreenCanvas renders blank page when a lot of images to draw

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I've got a problem with my Chrome Extension written in TS.
I'm using *OffscreenCanvas* (which are visible to the user) and *Worker*.
I want to pass array of images which is stored in string array of *DataUrls* in my worker class and draw them one after another in my canvas.
The problem is when array is small it draws as expected but when there is 20+ images in array I receive a blank page. I don't know why and how to fix this since there is no error messages.
Sharing my code, thank you very much in advance.

**worker.ts**

```
class ImageProcessor {
    private _canvas: OffscreenCanvas;
    private _chunk: EditorRequest[] = [];
    public constructor(canvas:OffscreenCanvas){
        this._canvas = canvas;
    }

    public DrawImages(images: ImageBitmap[]): void {
        var canvas = this._canvas;
        canvas.width = images[0].width;
        var canvasHeight: number = 0;
        images.forEach((x) => canvasHeight += x.height);
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

        // Get the 2D context of the canvas
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Draw each image onto the canvas
        var y = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img = images[i];
            context?.drawImage(img, 0, y);
            y += img.height;
        }
    }

    private async ConvertToImgs(chunks: EditorRequest[]): Promise<ImageBitmap[]> {
        let result: ImageBitmap[] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
            var chunk = chunks[I];
            for (var j = 0; j < chunk.images.length; j++) {
                var img = await fetch(chunk.images[j]).then(x => x.blob()).then(x => createImageBitmap(x));
                result.push(img);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public async Render(): Promise<void>{
        let images = await this.ConvertToImgs(this._chunk);
        this.DrawImages(images);
    }

    public Save(chunk:EditorRequest){
        this._chunk.push(chunk);
    }
}
var processor: ImageProcessor;
self.onmessage = async (msg) => {

    switch(msg.data.command){
        case "init": {
            processor = new ImageProcessor(msg.data.canvas);
            break;
        }
        case "chunk": {
            processor.Save(msg.data.chunk);
            break;
        }
        case "process": {
            await processor.Render();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
class EditorService {
    private _chunks: EditorRequest[] = [];
    private _worker: Worker;
    private _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

    public constructor(worker:Worker, canvas:HTMLCanvasElement){
        this._worker = worker;
        this._canvas = canvas;
    }

    public ProcessChunk(req: EditorRequest) {
        this._chunks.push(req);
        if (req.isLastChunk) {
            let offscreenCanvas = this._canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
            this._worker.postMessage({command:"init", canvas: offscreenCanvas},[offscreenCanvas]);
            for(var i = 0; i < this._chunks.length; i++){
                this._worker.postMessage({command:"chunk", chunk: this._chunks[i]});
            }
            this._worker.postMessage({command:"process"});
        }
    }
}
```